# How force text-only pasting in emacs?

Tags: microsoft-word, emacs, microsoft-powerpoint

On my mac I always have an emacs buffer open and occasionally I have to copy content from PowerPoint or Word.  Unfortunately, copying to the clipboard and yanking into emacs saves all the ugly formatting (and graphics) from the original document.  I only want to paste in the text (and never the formatting).  My current solution is to paste into TextWrangler and then repaste into emacs. What's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Marginally less annoying is to use [PlainClip](http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/plain-clip/):

> Plain Clip is a tiny Mac OS X application which will remove formatting
>   from text which is on the clipboard. It's designed as a face­less
>   application (i.e.: no graphical user interface, with the excep­tion of
>   the preferences win­dow), which makes it ideal for triggering it from
>   a hotkey / launcher applications such as Spark or Launch­Bar. For
>   users of such tools, Plain Clip offers a way to invoke it with a shell
>   command, which makes it possible to emulate a “Cmd-V” / “Paste”
>   keyboard shortcut after the clipboard’s content has been converted.